# How to use k means for a product recommendation dataset

Tags: python, data-mining, k-means, recommendation-engine, sklearn-pandas

I have a data set with columns titled as product name, brand,rating(1:5),review text, review-helpfulness. What I need is to propose a recommendation algorithm using reviews. I have to use python for coding here. data set is in .csv format.

To identify the nature of the data set I need to use kmeans on the data set. How to use k means on this data set?

Thus I did following,
1.data pre-processing,
2.review text data cleaning,
3.sentiment analysis,
4.giving sentiment score from 1 to 5 according to the sentiment value (given by sentiment analysis) they get and tagging reviews as very negative, negative, neutral, positive, very positive.

after these procedures i have these columns in my data set, product name, brand,rating(1:5),review text, review-helpfulness, sentiment-value, sentiment-tag.
This is the link to the data set https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YhCJNvV2BQk0T7PbPoR746DCL6tYmH7l/view?usp=sharing

I tried to get k means using following code It run without error. but I don't know this is something useful or is there any other ways to use kmeans on this data set to get some other useful outputs. To identify more about data how should i use k means in this data set..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.info()
X = np.array(df.drop(['sentiment_value'], 1).astype(float))
y = np.array(df['rating'])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(X)
KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300,
    n_clusters=2, n_init=10, n_jobs=1, precompute_distances='auto',
    random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you attach the dataset? Or atleast a sample of the csv file you have so we have something to work with?

Comment: okay. i will thanks for your response

Comment: This is the link to the data set https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YhCJNvV2BQk0T7PbPoR746DCL6tYmH7l/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You did not plot anything.

So nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are more specific about what you are trying to achieve we won't be able to help. Figure out what exactly you want to predict. Do you just want to cluster products according to their sentiment score which isn't especially promising or do you want to predict actual product preferences on a new dataset?

If you want to build a recommendation system the only possibility (considering your dataset) would be to identify similar products according to the rating/sentiment. Is that what you want?